# Request.GetResponseAsync() doesn't work in Background Task, no exception raised

Tags: c#, webrequest, background-task, getresponse

I'm doing an Universal Windows Platform app with Visual Studio and i'm facing a very strange problem. It's a Background Task on a Windows Runtime Component. The Background task executes without problem if the problematic part of code is removed.

When the code is reached the first sentence (`WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(_finalURI);`) is executed but `WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();` stops immediately the background task, without exception, without anything. Pretty weird.

```
     WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(_finalURI);
     WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync(); // Here it closes
     Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
     StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
     textResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

This is a very rare situation for me. [I uploaded a video to YouTube so you can see it as it happens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xW_ctXdC0eE). I've been through this more than two hours :( and keep trying.

EDIT:

I've changed to the class `HttpClient` and it's the same behavior.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
textResponse = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(_finalURI); // Here it closes
httpClient.Dispose();
```

EDIT 2:

Method signature, as requested by Scott Chamberlain:

```
public async Task<ArticleList> GetArticleList(ArticleAttributes attributes,
ImageResFromAPI imageres, string singleArticle)
```

Comment: because that exception is from another thread and does not refer to this thread you are trying to catch

Comment: @Adelaiglesia: Did you acquire a deferral?

Comment: Please include the method signature of the method you are calling this from

Comment: Did you find out why?  My app is doing the same

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem. Application closes without any exception. Even in `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`

Its pretty weird, but instead of using `await request.GetResponseAsync();`, if you use,

```
var webResponseTask = request.GetResponseAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(webResponseTask);

if (webResponseTask.IsFaulted)
  throw webResponseTask.Exception;

using (var webResponse = webResponseTask.Result)
{
}
```

you can bypass this issue.